# Tag from a array of buttons to open a new view with tag parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with opening a new view from my array buttons.
I have a NSLog message in place that is outputting a int that all works fine.

How do I get this button to open a viewController with my tag as a parameter.
This tag / parameter corresponds with a list of images that also seems to work fine.

How would I add this together?

Here is a code snippet from imageViewController.m:

```
-(void)thumbClickAction:(id)sender{


CustomImageView *club = (CustomImageView*)sender;

//debug line
NSLog(@"image tag : %d",club.tag);
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong I hope you can help me.

Comment: why are you using appdelegate? why can't you directly push the detail controller any specific reason?

Comment: No I took over this project from someone else and the code was a big mess when I got it

Comment: your problem in opening the viewcontroller right?

Comment: yes it doesn't open at all

Comment: wats your rootViewController NavigationController or ViewController

Comment: MainWindow.xib with a tab bar controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put Method as `-(void)thumbClickAction:(UIButton *)sender` instand of
 `-(void)thumbClickAction:(id)sender`

```
-(void)thumbClickAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
  NSLog(@"my button tag is - %d ",sender.tag);
  myNewViewController *newView = [[myNewViewController alloc] init];
  newView.myTag = sender.tag;
  [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

in above code create object `myNewViewController` pass you `sender.tag` to variale `myTag`(`myTag` is `NSString` Variale on `myNewViewController`) when you click on button then tag of button is go with `myTag` at `myNewViewController` and fire Query as you need.

Comment: The Image view still doesn't open :(

Comment: I want to open a view displaying a image corresponding to the tag.

Comment: you want to display image corresponding button click on anotherViewController ??..okay..where you store image ??

Comment: In a array arrImage this is coming from the sqlite DB

Comment: @SteinvanBroekhoven- i glad to help you..keep it up :)